# Salesforce Shield Encryption Evidence Post Spring 17 Release

Tags: shield-encryption

Post spring 17 release, the “View Encrypted Data” permission and its resulting masking behavior will no longer be available and users can see encrypted field data in plaintext if they have access to field.

In this case, as a developer how can we ensure that the data in the field is actually encrypted at rest/database after enabling encryption on a field? What kind of evidence we can provide to auditor if encryption is audit requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to ensure that your data is encrypted is to destroy your tenant secret. Once you do it, you should see "?????" for all your encrypted data instead of the actual plaintext value, and if you re-import your tenant secret, you should see your data showing up again.

Aside from this direct method, there are two recent ways that can hopefully help you asess the state of your data encryption wise and the usage of the encryption keys.

1. The encryption statistics give you more insight about the state of your data:

   https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_security_pe_encryption_statistics_beta.htm
2. If you also have the platform monitoring option (part of shield) you can have fine grain access to all the events related to the usage of your tenant secrets:

   https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_security_em_eventlogfile_platform_encryption.htm

Answer (score 0):

Per Salesforce

> **How Shield Platform Encryption Works**
>
> Shield Platform Encryption relies on a unique tenant secret that you control and a master secret
>   that's maintained by Salesforce. We combine these secrets to create your unique data encryption
>   key. We use that key to encrypt data that your users put into Salesforce, and to decrypt data
>   when your authorized users need it.
>
> When users submit data, the application server looks for the org-specific data encryption key in its
>   cache. If it isn’t there, the application server gets the encrypted tenant secret from the database
>   and asks the key derivation server to derive the key. The encryption service then encrypts the data
>   on the application server.
>   Salesforce securely generates the master and tenant secrets by using Hardware Security Modules
>   (HSMs). The unique key is derived by using PBKDF2, a Key Derivation Function (KDF), with the master
>   and tenant secrets as inputs.

For your team, this still means that the System Administrators have control over who can and cannot see encrypted information. You can test this by having a standard user try to view and encrypted field.
Salesforce can ensure your data is in fact encrypted. Below is an article on how this process works - essentially, the ciphertext can only be viewed by the tenant key holder that is saved in the Salesforce database.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_encryption_process.htm&type=5

Some helpful resources: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations.htm&type=5